# Timer drags a bit when too much is happening

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, timer

I'm working on a timer that needs to do some calculations and run some functions at a certain interval. I'm trying to keep the interval as big as possible, but I need it to be kind of fine grained.

Here is the periodic timer with some of the stuff that needs to happen.
So as you can see, every second (the milliseconds passed % 1000 == 0) it will do some stuff if some conditions are met. But also every 10 milliseconds I need to check some stuff.

It seems this is a bit too much, and after running the timer for 2 minutes it already drags 1 second behind. I guess I'm approaching this the wrong way. Could/should I somehow put all that logic in a function that just runs async so the timer can just keep going.

It's not the end of the world if the timer display drags for a few milliseconds every now and then, if it catches up later. But now the whole timer just drags.

```
_timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 10), (timer) {
  passedMilliseconds = passedMilliseconds + 10;

  // METRONOME BEEP AND BLINK
  if (passedMilliseconds % currentTimerSettingsObject.milliSecondDivider == 0) {
    _playMetronomeBeep();
    _startMetronomeBlink();
  }

  // ONE SECOND
  if (passedMilliseconds % 1000 == 0) {
    secondsDuration--;

    // COUNTDOWN
    if (secondsDuration < currentTimerSettingsObject.countDown + 1) {
      _player.play('sounds/beep.mp3');
    }

    // SET COUNTDOWN START VALUES
    if (secondsDuration == currentTimerSettingsObject.countDown) {
      isCountdown = true;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  // TIME IS UP
  if (secondsDuration < 0) {
    switchToNextTimer();
    notifyListeners();
  }
});
```

}

Comment: As documented in the `Timer` class API, you should use a `Stopwatch` for measuring elapsed time. This will be a lot better than trying to keep your own time counter logic. The API documentation for `Stopwatch` can be found here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Stopwatch-class.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot rely on a timer to deliver events exactly on time. You need to use a more exact method than simply incrementing a counter by 10 on every tick. One example would be to start a `Stopwatch` before the timer and then (knowing that your ticks will only be on approximately 10ms intervals) read `stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds` and base your decisions on that.

You will need to change your logic a bit. For example, you want to know when you pass a 1 second boundary. Previously, with your exact increments of 10 you knew you would eventually reach a round 1000. Now, you might see 995 followed by 1006, and need to deduce that you've crossed a second boundary to run your per second logic.

Comment: Thank you for this. It ended up being my solution. I run a stopwatch at the same time as a timer.periodic at 10ms. Then I floor the passed milliseconds from the stopwatch to the last past full 10 ms (i.e. 37890 until 37899 becomes 37890). Every periodic cycle I save the current floored passed milliseconds and compare it to the one form the previous cycle. This way I can do whatever I need with a granularity of 10ms.I do the same with seconds which gives the ability to do things every full seconds too.